# MongoDB Aggregate Operation Slowdown in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm experiencing a performance issue with the following MongoDB aggregate operation in my C# application:

```
var data = collection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToList();
```

Previously, it took about a minute to execute, but now it's taking 30+ minutes, without any noticeable changes to the code or database.

Any guidance on troubleshooting this unexpected slowdown would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

I've tried the following:

- Applying appropriate indexing
- Modifying the pipeline
- Checking for reported issues on MongoDB

Comment: Troubleshooting guidance: we need more information. What's the aggregation? Can you gather and share the `explain("allPlansExecution")` output for the aggregation? How many documents does the aggregation return? Is this running against an Atlas Cluster and, if so, what cluster size?